# Bad video and audio performance in all media players

Tags: nvidia, sound, video, youtube, pipewire

I am having trouble playing any video files on my desktop computer running Pop!_OS.

I have managed to get VLC to play audio at the correct time, but the video is delayed. YouTube videos start but freeze at about a second into the video.

Output from `inxi -Fxz`:

```
System:
  Kernel: 6.0.12-76060006-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    Desktop: GNOME 42.3.1 Distro: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
    base: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Jammy
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Hewlett-Packard product: p6-2060a v: 2.00
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: PEGATRON model: 2AC2 v: 2.00 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: AMI
    v: 7.13 date: 07/22/2011
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core i5-2310 bits: 64 type: MCP
    arch: Sandy Bridge rev: 7 cache: L1: 256 KiB L2: 1024 KiB L3: 6 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1795 high: 2281 min/max: 1600/3200 cores: 1: 1600
    2: 1600 3: 1700 4: 2281 bogomips: 23147
  Flags: avx ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GF119 [GeForce GT 520] vendor: Pegatron driver: nvidia
    v: 390.157 bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    gpu: nvidia resolution: 1: 1440x900~60Hz 2: 1216x684~50Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GT 520/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.157
    direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Family High Definition Audio
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
  Device-2: NVIDIA GF119 HDMI Audio vendor: Pegatron driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.1
  Device-3: Razer USA Seiren Mini type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 2-1.1:3
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.0.12-76060006-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: JACK v: 1.9.20 running: no
  Sound Server-3: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: no
  Sound Server-4: PipeWire v: 0.3.61 running: yes
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.82 TiB used: 29.25 GiB (1.6%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD10EZEX-08WN4A0
    size: 931.51 GiB
  ID-2: /dev/sdb type: USB model: External USB3.0 size: 931.51 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 914.84 GiB used: 29.12 GiB (3.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 1022 MiB used: 128.2 MiB (12.5%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sdb1
Swap:
  Alert: No swap data was found.
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 34.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 52 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 28%
Info:
  Processes: 257 Uptime: 17m Memory: 7.75 GiB used: 2.49 GiB (32.2%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.3.0 Packages: 2589 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13
```

Comment: You can check if the issue exists in Ubuntu and ask a new question. Pop OS is not supported in this site.

Comment: Great thank you, I will try that.